# Model Deforms once exported to Collada

Tags: mesh, rigging, export, import, collada

I have my model like this in blender in design,

[image: Model Design in Blender]

But once i convert it into Collada the model and reimport it deforms,

[image: After reimporting the collada file to the blender]

This might probably because of the additional mesh generated after rigging, anybody have an idea of what's going on and how to fix it?

Additionally the model file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ONfiyX4dwIe8VdKwqoaNWAy7uMv0M2oi/view?usp=sharing

And I use following options in exporting the collada file,

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any modifiers active during export? Try applying any active modifiers and then exporting. It might be an issue with the multires modifier if you have that on.

Comment: None, thanks for asking, included them as well in the question :)

Comment: Check the box that says apply modifiers under export data and then export again and see if anything changes. Also is there a reason why you need a collada file. Try exporting as FBX and see if you get the same issue

Comment: Tried adding modifiers, the problem persists, and unfortunately yes, the model need to be in collada format, as it need to be imported into an android application which only supports collada upto now :(

Comment: If it's not a modifier issue then try exporting with the Selection only option enabled when you export. You probably have extra geometry someone on another layer and its exporting everything in your blend file.

Comment: Then only the armature gets exported without the mesh :(

Comment: And problem persists with .fbx as well, it deforms

Comment: Select both the rig and the mesh and then export selected only. Did selection only at least fix the model problem?

Comment: That did it, I am a noob in this :( thanks for support, I'll flag this as answer.